# Are locks necessary to maintain thread safety when using memory cache in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, thread-safety, locking

I've been researching how to implement basic memory caching in my class library. I came across [this](https://michaelscodingspot.com/cache-implementations-in-csharp-net/) example and decided to implement something similar, but I've come across some problems:

- Is [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache) really thread-safe? Sifting through the comments, I've found people saying [it is](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/708) and some people saying [it isn't](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/359). I've never used this class before, so I'm not certain which comments apply to my situation.
- If `MemoryCache` is not thread-safe, how does one make it thread-safe? Or should I be using something different for my situation?

In my case, consuming applications will have **one instance** of my class (`DataProviderDecorator`) used by **1**-to-**N** threads. Will it be safe to use in that manner?:

```
public class DataProviderDecorator : IDataProvider
{
    private readonly IDataProvider Decoratee;
    private readonly MemoryCache Cache;                                         // System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> Locks { get; set; }     // System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary and System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim

    public object GetItem(string key)
    {
        object result = null;

        if (Cache.Contains(key))
        {
            return Cache.Get(key);
        }

        SemaphoreSlim cacheLock = Locks.GetOrAdd(key, new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
        cacheLock.Wait();

        try
        {
            if (Cache.Contains(key))
            {
                return (QueryResult)Cache.Get(key);
            }

            result = Decoratee.GetItem(key);

            CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
            cacheItemPolicy.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            if (!Cache.Add(key, result, cacheItemPolicy))
            {
                throw new Exception($"A record for the key [{key}] is already present in the cache.");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            cacheLock.Release();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Also, does anyone have any idea for how I should maintain the collection of locks? Presumably it would fill up indefinitely.

Comment: no and what does google say, and usually its how you implement it, but off the bat last i checked its thread safe. first hit on google `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149796/memorycache-thread-safety-is-locking-necessary`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20150112/4396852) in that thread seems to be contradictory. The person says `MemoryCache` is thread-safe, but their [code](https://github.com/haneytron/dache/blob/master/Dache.CacheHost/Storage/MemCache.cs#L214) seems to be using **locks**.
Also, the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089949/4396852) mentions threading issues related to the `Get` and `Contains` methods on `MemoryCache`.