# Is Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache thread safe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching

We are using .NET Core 3.1 and [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/3.1.24) (v3.1.24) and its implementation `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache`. I was reading the documentation about [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1). I didn't find any mention of thread safety of `IMemoryCache`. This is the snippet of how we use it:

```cs
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public TestController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult TestAction()
    {
        string key = "abc";
        if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out string cachedString))
        {
            cachedString = "new string";
            _memoryCache.Set(key, cachedString, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
        }
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Are `_memoryCache.TryGetValue` and `_memoryCache.Set` thread safe? Where is it mentioned in documentation?

Comment: `IMemoryCache` is an interface. What actual implementation are you using? [MS-provided MemoryCache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20150112/1043380)?

Comment: I edited the question. We are using `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache` implementation.

Comment: it is a fair observation that the docs should call this out explicitly; "it should be" is all I can say

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Yes, it's thread-safe.

If you look in to the source code for those `Set` extension methods, when used with `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache` you'll find the MemoryCache.SetEntry method.

In there, there is a `CoherentState` class that's backed by a Concurrent Dictionary for actual storage of cache entries. There's also a fair amount of code (and comments!) discussing updates/clears happening on other threads.

Answer (score -1):

It is when using atomic methods like:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCacheStore.cs,8a3844239e0386c7,references

Comment: I think you have linked to a different memory cache than what the questioner is referring to.