# Is Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, memorycache

According to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0#systemruntimecachingmemorycache), `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` is recommended over `System.Runtime.Caching/MemoryCache`.

`System.Runtime.Caching/MemoryCache` is thread safe as metioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). But is `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` also thread safe?

I couldn't find and doc says it's thread safe.

I looked into the source code. It is a wrapper around  **ConcurrentDictionary**. Can I consider it thread safe?
https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCache.cs

Comment: Dupe with no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72172240/is-microsoft-extensions-caching-memory-imemorycache-thread-safe